# group_concat filtering

Tags: mysql, group-by, filtering

I'm having trouble figuring out how should I query this.

table 1

```
id    client_name   Group_id     
------------------------------
1     IBM               1
2     DELL              1   
3     DELL              2
4     MICROSOFT         3 
5     DELL              2
6     MICROSOFT         2
7     HP                3 
7     HP                1
```

table 2

```
id    group_name
------------------
1     Group1      
2     Group2     
3     Group3
```

Using query below.

```
SELECT Client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(group_name)) merge_group , count(distinct(group_name)) as num_groups
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.Client_name
ORDER BY t1.Id having num_groups > 1
```

Would result from this

```
client_name      merge_group   
-------------------------
DELL               Group1,Group2
MICROSOFT          Group2,Group3
HP                 Group1,Group3
```

I need to filter the merge_group if I select Group2

result is this

```
client_name      merge_group   
-------------------------
DELL               Group1,Group2
MICROSOFT          Group2,Group3
```

or if I query Group1, result is this.

```
client_name      merge_group   
-------------------------
DELL               Group1,Group2
HP                 Group1,Group3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT Client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(group_name)) merge_group , count(distinct(group_name)) as num_groups
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2  ON t1.group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.Client_name
HAVING num_groups > 1
AND merge_group LIKE '%Group1%'
```

Comment: Great!... ive been looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce a where clause and filter the group name.

```
SELECT Client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(group_name)) merge_group , count(distinct(group_name)) as num_groups
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.group_id = t2.id
WHERE group_name = 'Group1' 
GROUP BY t1.Client_name
ORDER BY t1.Id having num_groups > 1
```

You can also do a string comparison using `HAVING` clause as well.

Answer (score 0):

`FIND_IN_SET()` method can be also used for filtering in such case. This is how it can be done:

```
SELECT
    client_name
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT group_name) AS merge_group
    , COUNT(DISTINCT group_name) AS num_groups
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.client_name
HAVING num_groups > 1
AND FIND_IN_SET('Group1', merge_group)
```

Comma is used as a default separator for `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so each group can be filtered as a set then. In many cases it will be safer than `REGEXP` or `LIKE`. They search words in a string what can be easily used in the case as above, but it would be risky to use with a big dataset, where one group name is a substring of another.